# Create a popup window with element from a drop down list

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to JavaScript, I need help with some code so that when I select an option from a drop down list a new window or popup should appear with the item selected.

```
<select name="select12">
    <option>- Select -</option>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="bmw">BMW</option>
    <option value="benz">Benz</option>
</select>
<button class="btn btn-normal" type="button" id="sign-in-button6">submit</button>
```

Comment: You really Dont want jQuery?

Comment: @PratikCJoshi Was that intended to be a joke?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example generates a genuine popup window with the item selected:

```
<select id="dropdown" name="select12">
    <option>- Select -</option>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="bmw">BMW</option>
    <option value="benz">Benz</option>
</select>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
```

```
window.myFunction = function() {
    var myWindow = window.open("", "", "width=200, height=100");
    var dd = document.getElementById("dropdown");
    myWindow.document.write(dd.options[dd.selectedIndex].innerHTML);
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e6yvom80/

Comment: @abhilash Unfortunately I'm not quite sure what you're asking. Can you please clarify? Thanks.

Comment: thank you for the reply if i select the benz car a new popup  should come with benz website by width of 400 and  height 400 (i mean like iframe) so that when my customer understand what they are buying.

Comment: @abhilash To accomplish this you can use `dd.options[dd.selectedIndex].innerHTML` to get the selected drop down, then use `window.open("http://www.your-web-address.com/", "", "width=400, height=400");` on the url you want based on the drop down selection.

Comment: thanks for the reply again ya i tried but its showing only the text if you want to try please check it

Comment: i need simple when my customer choose option  according to them a popup should come if he selected the BMW car an i frame should come with a bmw website and if he select the Volvo car  volvo website should come in i frame

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to achieve:

```js
function submitClicked() {
  var dropDown = document.getElementsByName('select12')[0];
  
  // Change .innerHTML to .value if you need value instead of text
  var selectedValue = dropDown.options[dropDown.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
  
  alert(selectedValue);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <select name="select12">
    <option>- Select -</option>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="bmw">BMW</option>
    <option value="benz">Benz</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" onclick="submitClicked();"/>
</form>
```

Comment: ya thanks for the reply but new window or pop is not displaying when i click submit button a new window should come or popup